Track the expdp task status that is run in cronjob
I'm currently working with housekeeping solution development for my team system.
The overall solution works as I expect. But when I check the log file, it shows that if I consecutively run expdp (because I need to dump one table at a time as they have different conditions to export the data), the expdp or the task that is run seems busy and skip some tables, and I need to access the DB server to manually run in the morning for those tables that are failed to dump.
When I manually run, I observe that if I run expdp too soon after finishing dumping the previous table, it throws these errors
Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 13 13:54:39 2024
Version 19.17.0.0.0
 
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
 
Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: nonexistent file or path [29434]

it seems that the previous expdp task may not finished processing something (but the dump file and log file are finished generating). I tried adding a delay (sleep 60) between each run (both in the shellscript and manually run), the situation got better, less expdp error, but if the table is really large, it's still cannot dump (maybe I can add more delay, but it will extend the task duration, which is not a good approach for the system that runs 24/7)
so I got an idea that I will have a function that check the oracle datapump task if it is still running by using
ps -ef | grep <sth like data pump task>
(maybe check every 15 seconds), if the command cannot find the task that does expdp, start dumping the next table.
But Im not sure if that expdp task has a specific name pattern?

you can try to export more than one table in one single datapump job even when you have different conditions in the where clause
File: <PARFILE_NAME>.par
-----------------
DIRECTORY = my_dir
DUMPFILE  = exp_query.dmp
LOGFILE   = exp_query.log
SCHEMAS   = hr, scott
INCLUDE   = TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPARTMENTS')"
QUERY     = scott.emp:"WHERE job = 'ANALYST' OR sal >= 3000"
# place following 3 lines on one single line:
QUERY     = hr.departments:"WHERE department_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
department_id FROM hr.employees e, hr.jobs j WHERE e.job_id=j.job_id
AND UPPER(j.job_title) = 'ANALYST' OR e.salary >= 3000)"


-- Run Export DataPump job:

%expdp system/<PASSWORD> parfile=<PARFILE_NAME>.par

Note that in this example the TABLES parameter cannot be used, because all table names that are specified at the TABLES parameter should reside in the same schema.

I tried that parfile+multiple table dump method but the dump file becomes too big for the dump path, so I divide the dump data to dump one table at a time and after dumping each table, I zip dumpfile+logfile so it doesn't use that much space.
There are around 21 tables that I need to dump daily (they are tables that store transaction data, and there are around 2k-3k transactions per day)
P.S. about schema difference, I think I can use something like .<table_name>, I ask DBA to set the pump schema to see the tables (they prefer creating another schema for datapumping task)
